# GA4 Views Doubled

Tags: google-analytics

URL: https://prc.versanthealth.com/

For some reason, views are doubled. Sessions, users, etc. are all similar to what I see in UA. Per GTM's debugger, page_view events are indeed being sent twice.

I don't know what to check for because GA4 is added via GTM and is only inserted into one area on the site. I have several other WordPress-based websites where GTM is added in the same fashion yet those views aren't doubled.

Reviewed code implementation and it is the standard GTM configuration.